# Rotation with Autolayout not working

Tags: objective-c, ios7, autolayout, ios-autolayout

the below method is not called when i rotate my device with Autolayout ON in IB.

```
willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
```

Firstly does the above methods don't wok with autolayout? the method gets called with Autolayout turned off. I am trying to change the background Image of my view on rotation, Not sure how to achieve that with autolayout constaints ON?

I also tried to use procedure by [Moin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170404/willrotatetointerfaceorientation-not-being-called-from-presented-viewcontroller) but I have a huge view hierarchy and the methods are called from superview onwards, and and i have lot of other code in other methods like. So it didn't help

```
didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation
```

Comment: You must be doing something incorrectly, because that method running shouldn't have anything to do with whether auto layout is on or off.  I always use auto layout, and that method works for me.

Comment: @rdelmar : thanks. So the methods get called automatically when i rotate the device. Only when I change my xib to autlayout they dont get called. I tested this on all the xib files and the methods didnt get called. So what could be possibly going wrong? because it works fine without autolayout. Is there something I am missing ?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. It's always worked for me. I just tried it on a new app with a xib defined controller, and it was called.

Comment: What's the root controller? A `UITabBarController`, a `UINavigationController` or neither ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer:
`-willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` **works** with AutoLayout.

The long answer:
Assuming you are using NIB, so many compounding issues can go wrong ; I have compiled this checklist:

1. Did you set your custom UIViewController in IB as recommended by @JoshJustice at [Loaded nib but the view outlet was not set - new to InterfaceBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763519/loaded-nib-but-the-view-outlet-was-not-set-new-to-interfacebuilder)
2. Are you properly handling auto-rotation as recommended by @nybon at [UIViewController does not auto rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416445/uiviewcontroller-does-not-auto-rotate)
3. Did you set a global orientation in the `plist` as recommended by @NateFlink at [Handling autorotation for one view controller in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502251/handling-autorotation-for-one-view-controller-in-ios7)
4. Does your custom UIViewController respond to `-supportedInterfaceOrientations` with incorrect values? See recommended response by @AndrewHershberger at [preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation must return a supported interface orientation (iOS 6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689474/preferredinterfaceorientationforpresentation-must-return-a-supported-interface-o)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Can you provide more detail on what did you meant by "Did you set your custom UIViewController in IB" and "Are you properly handling auto-rotation?"
as I said in my question, auto rotation works perfectly without autolayout.

Comment: There is no one answer for why it went wrong in your app (*until you find it that is*), but there is an answer to your question: *Firstly does the above methods work with autolayout?* **yes, they do** I have formatted my response and added links to the likely places you should look into.

Answer (score 1):

The `-willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` gets called on the root viewcontroller and all its child viewcontrollers and works with autolayout. If you want these methods to get called on a particular viewcontroller, It must be child viewcontroller of the root viewcontroller.

It took me a while to figure out that the hierarchy from the root to the last viewcontroller was breaking at some point. I just had to add it back as the child view controller.